# Remove duplicate rows from two dimensional list

Tags: c#

I have a two-dimensional list of strings (`List<List<string>>`).

Is there an easy way to remove the duplicate rows? That is the `List<string>` that are equal.

Comment: I would use the SelectMany to flatten the list and then the Distinct

Comment: What do you mean by _duplicate rows_? Same order with same items in all `List<string>` items?

Answer (score 1):

Build a custom [IEqualityComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) based on [SequenceEqual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
class ListComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<string>>
{
    public bool Equals(List<string> x, List<string> y)
    {
        if (x == y) 
           return true ; 

       if (x == null || y == null) 
           return false ;

        // Order if you need

        return x.SequenceEqual(y) ; 
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<string> obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
           return 0;

        unchecked
        {
           return obj.Select(e => e.GetHashCode()).Aggregate(17, (a, b) => 23 * a + b);
        }
    }
}
```

Apply [Distinct()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb338049(v=vs.110).aspx) with the comparer :

```
List<List<string>> original = ... 
var sortedListOfList = original.Distinct(new ListComparer()).ToList() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify if the lists should be compared with or without ordering.

Without ordering it should be:

```
List<List<string>> source = *yourLists*;
var sortedList = source.Distinct();
```